# Android NullPointerException in Retrofit response

Tags: android, api, callback, nullpointerexception, retrofit

In my activity I have more than one Retrofit services operations and these services relay on same Retrofit Callback methods. And these causes null pointer when one service try to get a callback at the same time callback is used by other service, how to fix this problem?

I have been using retrofit for my webservice calls. It is working fine in emulator but when I use a real device it crashes and got the error log as:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.itmam.info.jadara.Notiﬁcations.Notifications_Items_Adapter$4.onResponse(Notifications_Items_Adapter.java:309)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8147)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

This is my Retrofit client class:

```
public class RetrofitGeneral {

private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static final String BASE_URL = "My_URL";

public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
 }
}
```

This is my Retrofit Service interface:

```
public interface getClientDetails {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("WebService.asmx/SelectClientById")
Call<List<ClientDetails>> getClientdetails(
        @Field("ClientID") int ClientID,
        @Field("Token") String Token,
        @Field("CurrentEmployeeID") int CurrentEmployeeID
 );
}
```

And this way i am making a call to Retrofit service from my adapter onBindViewHolder that call the retrofit more than one time:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Notifications_Items_Adapter.Notifications_Holder holder, int position) {
    myHolder = holder;
    holderList.add(holder);
    getTaskId(position);
    getTaskDetails(taskID);

}
```

This is my retrofit callBack method:

```
private void getTaskDetails(int taskID){
    getTaskDetails getTaskDetails=RetrofitGeneral.getRetrofitInstance().create(getTaskDetails.class);
    Call<List<Task>> listCall=getTaskDetails.getDetails(taskID,Log_in.getToken(),Log_in.CurrentEmployeeID);
    listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Task>>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Task>> call, Response<List<Task>> response) {
            task = response.body().get(0); // Error here after the second call. 
            tasksList.add(task);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Task>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Please help :)

Comment: In my activity I have more than one Retrofit services operations and these services relay on same Retrofit Callback methods. And these causes null pointer when one service try to get a callback at the same time callback is used by other service, how to fix this problem?

Comment: You are getting null pointer exception on the list you are using in your code. Please make sure you initialized the list before calling any function on that list. I see more than one list you are using in your code. Please check which list causing the error by using the line number shown in log.

Comment: All lists initialized before calling any function, the error causes by task = response.body().get(0); because the response returned null with code 500.
@DeepakRai

Comment: Like I said you need to be sure when calling any method on a list. response.body() return a list and you are calling get(0) on it without checking it is null or not. Also you getting null with 500 due to internal server error. Confirm your calling request is correct or discuss same with your  backend developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by using Retrofit Synchronous like that :

```
UserService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(UserService.class);

// 1. Calling '/api/users/2' - synchronously

Call<UserApiResponse> callSync = service.getUser(2);

try
{
  Response<UserApiResponse> response = callSync.execute();
  UserApiResponse apiResponse = response.body();

  //API response
  System.out.println(apiResponse);
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

from [Retrofit 2 – Synchronous and asynchronous call example](https://howtodoinjava.com/retrofit2/retrofit-sync-async-calls/).

Answer (score 2):

The error is because of this line

`Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

listCall.enqueue makes the network call on background Thread and you can't display a toast from background thread, you have to use Main thread to display a toast.

You can use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong...Please try later!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

To fix the error.

For the answer why your call is failing you can print the stacktrace to figure that out

```
 @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Task>> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong...Please try later!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, The Runtime Exception has been resolved but I got another exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onResponse(Call<SalaryListModel> call, Response<SalaryListModel> 
response) {

 if (response.isSuccessful()) {

    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: calling");

 if (response.body().getStatus_code() == 200) {

    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: calling 200");

            }

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: else--");
            if (response.code() == 500) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: 500");

                //and if you want to parse your error body try this

                /*
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    YourErrorClass error = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().charStream(), YourErrorClass.class);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                     Log.e(TAG, "onResponse error: " + e.getMessage());
                }*/



            } else if (response.code() == 406) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: 406");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: esle");
            }

        }

    }
```